# no se como capturar lo que quiero con scrappy php

Tags: php, mysql

hola estoy haciendo un codigo php para recorrer los array ya funciona todo el problema es que quiero que me capture solo la parte de stremium

este es el script que se encuentra en la web

```
<script>
    var videos =[["Streamium","https:\/\/streamium.xyz\/gocdn.html#SVBVa0RKT3JhZmdCeThLVkkvK0pTVU5HREllY1ZpbjY0ampPdEdWc0ZQeTRtK2pSUHIyK0hyNzNadTZjVmJoV2NIOWtvaGRUTGxCQWJETzdhSXVzL2c9PQ==",0],["Fembed","https:\/\/www.fembed.com\/v\/pmo5-37w89l",0],["Mega","https:\/\/mega.nz\/embed#!ZOhmnACT!Sva_2yxdzkU_tjwYSJ40NkGAS-DGm5lV-7wY4q6zNPg",0],["Amus","https:\/\/v.tioanime.com\/embed.php?s=amus&v=TDAxWmlCZWlIbldpUyt5Z1M5WGRYTzNMTWYySnhKbXQvcVI4Z1J4YlM3cTZrUStjQlZqcXJyTFdZQUdaaFdHV3YrT3huVjBkZDhUb3cvRlFlei9RVmUzTkpOdi9wSmhKcmtPOUJHczIzRzQ9",0],["Mepu","https:\/\/v.tioanime.com\/embed.php?s=mepu&v=RHdRSE1OeXNVVUt5eVBCYytZVkNiOXdveVdFcExnOXNaZEtwMy9EWHpSYz0=",0],["YourUpload","https:\/\/www.yourupload.com\/embed\/7OwB16NkYoIA",0],["Netu","https:\/\/hqq.tv\/player\/embed_player.php?vid=244222256260277257271230271231223238194271217261258",0]];

     $(document).ready(function () {
       initEpisode();
});
```

y este es mi codigo en php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
$link = $_POST['link'];

for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
$ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link.$i);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


     $resultado = curl_exec($ch); 

    if(preg_match_all('/"Stremium","https:\/\/streamium.xyz\/gocdn.html"(.*)"/',$resultado, $matches)){
        echo "<p>insert into series(nombre,capitulos)values(nombre.".$matches[1][0].")</p>";
    }
  }
 }
  ?>
```

me pueden dar una mano? gracias he intentado de todo pero me obtiene la array de todos los servidores

insert into series(nombre,capitulos)values(nombre.,"https://hqq.tv/player/embed_player.php?vid=244222256260277257271230271231223238194271217261258)

```
    insert into series(nombre,capitulos)values(nombre.,"https:\/\/hqq.tv\/player\/embed_player.php?vid=204207205268241263272274274230206263194271217261258)
```

este es el resultado que tengo y es el que quiero pero quiero que contenga stremium que esta en la primera fila y ese es mi problema que captura todos los array de videos y no el de la fila que quiero

Comment: pero el problema lo tengo en el preg_match_all y yo acabo de poner en el titulo respecto al tema

Comment: Puedes incluir unas lineas de ejemplo del contenido de '$resultado' tal cual como se obtiene, y cual es la salida que deseas. Sin ello es difícil saber cómo procesar el texto y obtener el resultado que quieres.

Comment: ahh bueno gracias ahora edito todo la publicacion

Comment: ya acabo de editar la publicacion